# How can I update a picker with a value stored in CoreData in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am writing an App to store Points of Interest in icloud. The visualisation is either a map with annotations or a list.
To select the Type of the Poi I use a Picker based on an enum:

```
import SwiftUI

enum Poitypes: String, Hashable, CaseIterable {
    case dogStation = "Dog Station"
    case trash = "Mülleimer"
    case poop = "Hundehaufen"
    case bag = "Hundebeutel"
    
}



struct PoiTypeView: View {
    @State private var selection = Poitypes.dogStation
    @State private var showsPicker: Bool = false
    @Binding var selectedPoi: Poi
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Welcher Type befindet sich hier?")
                .padding(20)
            Picker(selection: $selection, label: Text("POI Type")) {
                ForEach(Poitypes.allCases, id:\.self) { value in
                    Text(value.rawValue)
                        .tag(value)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(InlinePickerStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

The attribute I store the POItype is of type string:
[Screenshot of entity][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgcfa.png

Selecting a value I store the tag - so far so good.

When I want to update a POI from the list or map view, how can I achieve that the picker is showing the stored selection?
I store the selected POI in an object of Type POI and pass it to the picker view.
But then I do not know how to "convert" the string to be of type Poitypes so that the selection will be updated.

Comment: Not sure I got this right but to get an enum value from an associated type in general you use `init(rawValue:)`. So here it would be something like `selection = Poitypes(rawValue: selectedPoi.poitype)` but note that the init returns an optional value so you need to handle that also

Comment: But the value in selectedPoi.poitype equals to the tag, not the raw value, e.g. here is stored "trash", the raw value would be "Mülleimer"

Comment: I missed that part but it doesn’t make sense in my opinion to do that. Now you need a function in your enum that given a tag (string) returns the correct enum item

Comment: So you mean I should always store the raw value, not the tag?

Comment: yes, to me that make much more sense

Comment: I will try it, thanks a lot.